# car_parking_system .I have a problem when i simulate my program . It is program describe car parking system

Tags: verilog

I have a  problem with my program. When `password ==2'b10` or `2'b01`, state of my program is `WRONG_PASS`. But when I change `password==2'b11` then state wasn't `RIGHT_PASS`. It until `WRONG_PASS`.

```
module car_parking_system( 
                input clk,reset,
 input sensor_entrance, sensor_exit, 
 input [1:0] password,
 output wire GREEN_LED,RED_LED,YELLOW_LED,output reg [2:0] counter_wait_output,output reg [2:0] number_enter_output ,output led_com
    );
 parameter IDLE = 3'b000, WAIT_PASSWORD = 3'b001, WRONG_PASS = 3'b010, RIGHT_PASS = 3'b011,STOP = 3'b100;
 // Moore FSM : output just depends on the current state
wire ck_1HZ;
assign led_com=1'b1;
 clk_1hz divider_1HZ(clk,ck_1HZ);
 reg[2:0] current_state, next_state;
 reg[32:0] counter_wait;
 reg red,green,yellow;
 reg [2:0] number_enter;
 // Next state
 initial begin 
    number_enter = 0;
    counter_wait = 0;
     end
 always @(posedge ck_1HZ or negedge reset)
 begin
 if(~reset) 
 current_state = IDLE;
 else
 current_state = next_state;
 end
 // counter_wait
 always @(posedge ck_1HZ or negedge reset) 
 begin
 if(~reset) 
 counter_wait <= 0;
 else if(current_state==WAIT_PASSWORD)
 counter_wait <= counter_wait + 1;
 else 
 counter_wait <= 0;
 end
 // change state
// fpga4student.com FPGA projects, Verilog projects, VHDL projects
 always @(*)
 begin
 case(current_state)
 IDLE: begin
         if(sensor_entrance == 1)
 next_state = WAIT_PASSWORD;
 else
 next_state = IDLE;
 end
 WAIT_PASSWORD: begin
 if(counter_wait < 5  && password==2'b11)
 next_state = RIGHT_PASS;
 else if( counter_wait > 5 && password==2'b00)
 next_state=STOP;
 else if (password==2'b01|| password==2'b10)
 next_state =WRONG_PASS;
 else 
 next_state=WAIT_PASSWORD;
 end

WRONG_PASS: begin
  if(password==2'b11) // Correct password after wrong attempts
    next_state = RIGHT_PASS;
  else // Any other password (incorrect or timeout)
    next_state = WRONG_PASS;
  number_enter <= number_enter +1;
end
 
 
 RIGHT_PASS: begin
 if((sensor_entrance==1 && sensor_exit == 1)||number_enter >3 )
 next_state = STOP;
 else if(sensor_exit == 0 && sensor_entrance==0)
 next_state = IDLE;
 else
 next_state = RIGHT_PASS;
 end
 STOP: begin
 if(sensor_entrance==1 && sensor_exit==0)
 next_state = WAIT_PASSWORD;
 else  
 next_state = STOP;
 end
 default: next_state = IDLE;
 endcase
 end
 // LEDs and output, change the period of blinking LEDs here
 always @(*) begin 
 case(current_state)
 IDLE: begin
 green = 1'b0;
 red = 1'b0;
 yellow = 1'b0;

 end
 WAIT_PASSWORD: begin
 green = 1'b0;
 red = 1'b1;
 yellow=1'b0;

 end
 WRONG_PASS: begin
 green = 1'b0;
 red = ~ck_1HZ;
 yellow=1'b0;
 
 end
 RIGHT_PASS: begin
 green = ~ck_1HZ;
 red = 1'b0;
 yellow=1'b0;
 
 end
 STOP: begin
 green = 1'b0;
 red= 1'b0;
 yellow=~ck_1HZ;

 end
 endcase
 end
 
 always @(posedge clk) begin
    counter_wait_output <= counter_wait;
  end
  always @(posedge clk) begin 
  number_enter_output <= number_enter ;
  end
   
 assign RED_LED = red ;
 assign GREEN_LED = green;
 assign YELLOW_LED =yellow;
 endmodule
 
 module clk_1hz (
  input clkht,
  output reg clk
);

  integer d1hz_r;
  integer d1hz_n;
  parameter N = 5   ; 

  initial begin
    d1hz_r = 0;
    d1hz_n = 0;
  end

  always @(posedge clkht) begin
    d1hz_r <= d1hz_n;
  end

  always @* begin
    if (d1hz_r == N) begin
      d1hz_n <= 0;
    end else begin
      d1hz_n <= d1hz_r + 1;
    end
  end

  always @* begin
    clk = (d1hz_r < N/2) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
  end
endmodule
```

My Test Bench is as follow:

```
module tb_car_parking_system;

  // Inputs
  reg clk;
  reg reset;
  reg sensor_entrance;
  reg sensor_exit;
  reg [1:0] password;
  wire [2:0] counter_wait_output;
  wire [2:0] number_enter_output;

  // Outputs
  wire GREEN_LED;
  wire RED_LED;
  wire YELLOW_LED;

  // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
  car_parking_system uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .reset(reset), 
    .sensor_entrance(sensor_entrance), 
    .sensor_exit(sensor_exit), 
    .password(password), 
    .GREEN_LED(GREEN_LED), 
    .RED_LED(RED_LED),
    .YELLOW_LED(YELLOW_LED),
    .counter_wait_output(counter_wait_output),
    .number_enter_output(number_enter_output)
  );

  // Monitor for displaying inputs and outputs
  initial begin
    $monitor("Time=%0t clk=%b reset=%b sensor_entrance=%b sensor_exit=%b password=%b GREEN_LED=%b RED_LED=%b YELLOW_LED=%b counter_wait_output=%b number_enter_output=%b",
             $time, clk, reset, sensor_entrance, sensor_exit, password, GREEN_LED, RED_LED, YELLOW_LED, counter_wait_output, number_enter_output);
  end

  // Clock generation
  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #10 clk = ~clk;
  end

  // Testbench stimulus
  initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    reset = 0;
    sensor_entrance = 0;
    sensor_exit = 0;
    password = 0;
    #100;
    reset = 1;
    #20;
    sensor_entrance = 1;
    password = 0;
    #100;
    password = 1;
    #1000;
    password = 2;
    #1000;
    password = 3;
    sensor_entrance = 1;
    // Add stimulus here
  end

endmodule
```

[image]

I don't know where did I do wrong. I have attached an image that shows result of my program when I run test bench.

Answer (score 1):

`number_enter <= number_enter +1;` in the `WRONG_PASS` state is creating a combinational loop because this is written in the combinational block (`always @(*) begin`). For me it was causing the simulation to give an error `ERROR: [Simulator 45-1] A fatal run-time error was detected.  Simulation cannot continue.`

Here is the thing that I changed. I commented `number_enter <= number_enter +1;` in the `WRONG_PASS` state and I was able to simulate it with the intended behavior as can be seen in the figure below:

```
WRONG_PASS: begin
    if(password==2'b11) // Correct password after wrong attempts
        next_state = RIGHT_PASS;
    else // Any other password (incorrect or timeout)
        next_state = WRONG_PASS;
    //number_enter <= number_enter +1;
end
```

[image]

Now you have to rewrite your logic for the `number_enter` in an `always @ (posedge Clk_1Hz)` block.